# Is this abbrevation of ARMY and NAVY true?

Tags: etymology

Recently I realized that teachers at a local school were teaching the following to primary students:

> What is the expanded form of army? Alert Regular Mobility Young

Searching this online I also stumbled on yet another suspicious abbreviation.

> Navy: Nautical Army of Volunteer Yeomen

These abrevations were confirmed online [here](https://www.pw.live/exams/full-form/army/#:%7E:text=Indian%20Army%20renowned%3F-,What%20is%20ARMY%3F,helicopters%20to%20support%20ground%20combatants), [here](https://www.cheggindia.com/full-forms/army/), [here](https://www.pw.live/exams/full-form/navy/#:%7E:text=fleet%20in%20Japan%3F-,The%20full%20form%20of%20NAVY%20is%3A%20Nautical%20Army%20of%20Volunteer,or%20ocean%2Dborne%20fighting%20maneuvers) and lot many other credible Indian websites. But I am skeptical of the same. Please let me know if these are true or not.

Comment: [Navy](https://www.etymonline.com/word/navy#etymonline_v_2338) and [Army](https://www.etymonline.com/word/army#etymonline_v_17012) are not acronyms.

Comment: That is nonsense.

Comment: OK thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I don't get why this was downvoted. It's an interesting question, even if the answer happens to be "no." Plus, the OP cites multiple references, so the question isn't just based on hearsay. I've given it +1

Comment: It's possible that when the Indian army adopted the word "army", they attached some meaning behind the word... but as for the words in the English, a quick search of their etymology shows otherwise. Also it would be strange that your "NAVY" has the the acronym "ARMY" in it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are backronyms at best (NOAD: "a fanciful explanation of a word's origin"), and even then apparently only according to Indians. Here's why these words aren't acronyms etymologically:

- Both words date back to Middle English (when acronyms were almost unheard of) and have other etymologies according to the Middle English Dictionary (MED): "[OF armée, from L ppl. armāta](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED2262)" and "[OF navie & nave(e.](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED29144)"
- The first word of each purported acronym only entered English in the 16th century, after army/navy. The same is true of "volunteer" (See NOAD.)
- The words were not spelled the same in Middle English. For example, armee, armeye, harme; naue, nauee, navie
- Neither purported acronym makes much sense. "Alert Regular Mobility Young" is not grammatical/idiomatic (except maybe to Indians, I don't know Indian English well enough to say). A navy also doesn't usually have volunteers—it is a job. The words *army* and *navy* also often refer to something other than people (according to the MED): "a military expedition (by land or sea)" and "Ships; a group of ships; fleet; also, naval transports" as examples respectively.

Comment: NOAD = New Oxford American Dictionary